# コンパイル時にネイティブエンディアンを判定するには？

Tags: c++, c++11

実行時にネイティブエンディアンがリトルエンディアンか否かは、例えば以下のように判定できます。

```
#include <iostream>

const int bom = 1;
bool is_little_endian() {
    return *reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&bom) == 1;
}

int main()
{
    const bool b = is_little_endian();
    std::cout << b << '\n';
}
```

C++11で定数式の機能(constexpr)が追加されたので、constをconstexprに変えればコンパイル時に判定できるのではないかと考えたのですが、reinterpret_castは定数式の中では使えないようで、コンパイルエラーになります。

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int bom = 1;
constexpr bool is_little_endian() {
    return *reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&bom) == 1;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr bool b = is_little_endian();
    std::cout << b << '\n';
}
```

;

```
# clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 test_endian.cpp
test_endian.cpp:4:16: error: constexpr function never produces a constant
      expression [-Winvalid-constexpr]
constexpr bool is_little_endian() {
               ^
test_endian.cpp:5:10: note: reinterpret_cast is not allowed in a constant
      expression
        return *reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&bom) == 1;
                ^
1 error generated.
```

コンパイル時にはネイティブエンディアンは決まっていると思うのでコンパイル時に判定したいのですが、Boostライブラリのようにコンパイラー独自のマクロで判定する方法以外で、何か方法はありますか？

※リトルエンディアンか否かだけではなく、リトルエンディアン／ビッグエンディアン／その他に分類できればベストです。

---

■追記
用途としては、外部データと内部データを変換する関数／クラスを作る場合に、外部データのエンディアンとネイティブエンディアンの関係で実装を最適化する、ということを想定しています。

Comment: コンパイル時に定数展開されるような式が欲しいってことですか？オイラだったら #if BIG みたいに書きたくなるので結局マクロが欲しくなっちゃいます。

Comment: g++ 5.1.0 ではコンパイル通りました。

Comment: constexpr union endian_tester_type { int one; char islittle; } endian_tester = {1}; だとコンパイル通りますが gcc-4.8.3 とか gcc-4.5.3 だと最適化指示に関係なく実行時判断になりました。 visual c++ 2008 だと最適化指示ありでは定数展開された様子です。まあマクロに使えないのでオイラ的には無用の長物ですが。

Comment: @774RR
共用体を使うと、“accessing 'endian_tester_type::islittle' member instead of initialized 'endian_tester_type::one' member in constant expression”みたいなコンパイルエラーになりませんか？

Comment: あっとごめん。 constexpr でなくて const で試していました (VC++2008 は constexpr 使えないので)
int func() { return endian_tester.islittle; } として使います (endian_tester_type でなくて endian_tester) 警告にもエラーにもならないはずですが。 VC++ は MOV EAX, 1 を生成し、定数展開しています。 GCC は movsbl _ZL13endian_tester, %eax を生成したので実行時判断です。

Comment: @masm
そうなんですか！
手元のg++ 4.9.2では、clang 3.5.1と同様にコンパイルエラーになります。

Comment: gcc-5.1 で、 `std::cout << is_little_endian() << '\n';` ではコンパイルエラーになりませんけど、`constexpr bool le = is_little_endian();` だとコンパイルエラーになります。要は、is_little_endian() の結果は非 `constexpr` な値として使うことはできるけど、`constexpr` な値としては使えないということです。

Comment: `constexpr` として扱おうとすると、禁止されるものに (1) `union` の、代入したメンバーとは異なるメンバーの参照、(2) `void *` から別の型のポインタへの変換、(3) `reinterpret_cast` が含まれている (※) ので、`int` 型変数の先頭バイトを取り出すのは無理な気がします。 (※) ISO/IEC 14882:2011,2014 5.19 p2 より。

Comment: なるほど。`is_little_endian()`の使い方の例が良くなかったのですね。修正します。

Comment: 特定の処理系や言語に依存しない方法として、ビルド時に「エンディアンを判定してヘッダファイルなりを生成する小さなプログラム」をコンパイル&実行してから本体をコンパイルする、という伝統的な手法もあると思います。

最近はこういう多段ビルドってあまり流行らないのかもしれませんが。それとクロスコンパイルでは使えないという欠点もあります。

Comment: @shirok
ごもっともです。
ただ、今度はビルドシステムが環境に依存するという問題に悩まされそうですが…。

Answer (score 4):

[yoh2さんコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/11458/#comment10371_11458)にある通り、C++14時点のconstexpr関数ではコンパイル時エンディアン判定は不可能です。本家SOの類似質問でも全てNO回答です。

- [Is there a way to do a C++ style compile-time assertion to determine machine's endianness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280162/)
- [constexpr and endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583791/)

Boost Libraryを使用できる環境ならば、下記が便利かと思います。いずれもC++03から使えるヘッダオンリーライブラリです。

- Boost Predefの[`BOOST_ENDIAN_*`マクロ](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/predef/doc/html/predef/reference/other_macros.html)
- [Boost Endian Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/endian/doc/)（Boost 1.58.0以降）

---

**追記：** まだC++17正式発行前で気の早い話ですが、将来のC++標準ライブラリ(C++20)には [`std::endian`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian) が追加され、コンパイル時のネイティブエンディアン判定が可能になります。

```
// require C++20
# include <type_traits>
constexpr bool is_little_endian() {
    return std::endian::native == std::endian::little;
}
```

(via https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6ngkgc/2017_toronto_iso_c_committee_discussion_thread/)

Comment: あれ？[C言語スタイルキャストかつ参照](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27088447/4955179)だと、GCCでもClangでもコンパイルできますね。
別の型での参照がOKかつ確実に下位バイトを参照できるなら、これでいけそうですが…

Comment: リンク先のように、 `(const char &)bom` と書くと、 `static_cast<const char &>(bom)` と同義なので、エンディアンにかかわらず `1` に評価されてしまいます。

Comment: `(const uint8_t&)uint32_`は`uint32_t`から`uint8_t`へのキャスト、つまりエンディアンに関わらず下位8bitの抽出が行われますから、常にLittle Endianと誤判定されるだけです。（＝yoh2さんと同意見） 参考リンク https://goo.gl/GByM0I

Comment: そういうキャストになるのですか。残念です。
また、ビッグエンディアンなマシン用のコンパイルサービスを知らなかったのでgcc.godbolt.orgも参考になりました。（これで他サイトのように実行もできると良いのですが。）

Answer (score 1):

標準のものかどうかはなはだ疑問ではありますが、CentOS では /usr/include/ 下とか MacOS では /usr/include/machine/ 下とかに endian.h といふのがあるやうです。

```
#include <machine/endian.h>

#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
...
#elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
...
#endif
```

Comment: `<*/endian.h>`は、[Boostライブラリの実装](https://github.com/boostorg/predef/blob/master/include/boost/predef/other/endian.h)を見ると、C標準ライブラリやOSに依存しているようです。GCC/*BSD/MacOSはカバーできそうなので、後は（glibcを使わない場合の）ClangとWindowsをカバーできればメジャーな環境では大丈夫かもしれませんね。